# Why my scene is black until OrbitControl is called in ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Why do I need to click and move the cursor a little before I can see the scene in ThreeJS?

So, the page is completely black, but once I click and move, everything appears, I can't find the problem. A little help would be nice :)

```
    var origWidth = 1280;
    var origHeight = 720;
    //TODO WindowResize looks wierd, implement it properly
    //var width = window.innerWidth;
    //var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = origWidth;
    var height = origHeight;

    var Top = origHeight/2;
    var Bottom = -origHeight/2;
    var Left = -origWidth/2;
    var Right = origWidth/2;


    var renderer = null;
    var scene = null;
    var camera = null;
    var Textures = {};

        //Set the renderer engine
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;



        //Setup the Scene!
        scene = new THREE.Scene;

        //Camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, origWidth / origHeight, 0.1, 10000);
        camera.position = new THREE.Vector3(0,-80,800);

        scene.add(camera);
        camera.lookAt(scene);
        //TODO WindowResize looks wierd, implement it properly
        //var windowResize = THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);



        //Light
        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 0, 900);
        scene.add(pointLight);



        //Debug
        controlsObj = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
        controlsObj.addEventListener('change', render);
        axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( origWidth );
        scene.add( axes );

        /*var size = 10;
        var step = 1;
        var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( size, step );

        gridHelper.position = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 10, 0 );
        gridHelper.rotation = new THREE.Euler( 45, 0, 0 );

        scene.add( gridHelper );*/

        var pointLightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper( pointLight, 10 );
        scene.add( pointLightHelper );

        //Add playing field
        tablegeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(origWidth, origHeight, 40);
        tablematerial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, map: Textures.bg, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        tableobj = new THREE.Mesh(tablegeometry, tablematerial);
        tableobj.position.set(0,0,-20); //TODO vec
        scene.add(tableobj);

        //ANNNND, Action !
        render();

    function render() {
        console.log("render");
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

Comment: This is likely to be unrelated but, please change `gridHelper.position = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 10, 0 );` to `gridHelper.position.set( 10, 10, 0 )` and `gridHelper.rotation = new THREE.Euler( 45, 0, 0 );` to `gridHelper.rotation.set( 45, 0, 0 );`.

Comment: Thanks mrdoob, will do. But I think I took those lines from your Docs (must be outdated a little). Glad to "meet" you!!! :)

Comment: Thanks! Cleaned that up :)

Comment: It is likely because the camera is not looking at the scene. Experiment with a single call to `camera.lookAt( scene.position )`. Better yet, try the recent version of three.js r.67.

Comment: THanks WestLangley, will do! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was positioning the camera after calling OrbitControls. I just called OrbitControls after creating the camera, and it worked fine.

In your case try to add : requestAnimationFrame(render); in the render function.

```
function render() {
    console.log("render");
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

So that in the first call of render(); the scene should appear.

Comment: Static scenes do not require an animation loop. It is best not to add an animation loop unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Orbit control object before render() function, here is solution!

```
controlsObj.update();
```